# Remove index method stopping at first index(java string array)

Tags: java, list, loops, methods, indexing

so I have this loop to basically go through and arraylist of string,and then remove an element from it if found:

```
public static void delete(List<String> users) {
    boolean boucleretrait = true;
    while (boucleretrait) {
        System.out.print("del a user(1) or quit(2)?;");
        Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choicedel = choice.nextInt();
        if (retraitchoix == 1) {
            for (int index = 0; index < users.size(); index++) {
                Scanner element = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("enter name to delete \n");
                String elementdelete = element.nextLine();

                if (users.get(index).equals(elementdelete)) {
                    users.remove(index);
                    System.out.print(users);
                } else {
                    System.out.print("not present\n");
                    retrait(users);
                    boucleretrait = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, the method just compare to the first element in the list and if its not the right one,just go in the else loop without checking the others.I dont know how to fix that.Heres my arraylist if needed:

```
ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
users.add("bob");
users.add("matthew");
users.add("Albert");
usagers.add("Jon");
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
if(users.get(index).equals(elementdelete)){
    users.remove(index);
    System.out.print(users);
}
```

you want something like

```
if(users.contains(elementdelete)) {
    users.remove(elementdelete);
    System.out.print(users);
}
```

You may wish to make the comparison with *contains* case insensitive by using *toLowerCase*. For this, you will need to change your entries in the list to

```
ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
users.add("bob");
users.add("matthew");
users.add("albert");
users.add("jon");
```

and then use

```
if(users.contains(elementdelete.toLowerCase())) {
```

I don't think you need the *for* loop at all.

Answer (score 0):

What's currently happening is it's entering the `for` loop, checking the first user, getting false for `users.get(index).equals(elementdelete)` so it doesn't enter the if, enters the else, and then sets `boucleretrait` to `false`, so it exits the `while` loop. So setting `boucleretrait` to false should happen after all users have been checked.

As well as that, asking the user for a name should also happen outside the `for` loop or else it will ask for a new name every time it loops through to check the next user in your `ArrayList`.

Keeping that in mind, you could rewrite this section of code:

```
if (retraitchoix == 1) {
    for (int index = 0; index < users.size(); index++) {
        Scanner element = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("enter name to delete \n");
        String elementdelete = element.nextLine();

        if (users.get(index).equals(elementdelete)) {
            users.remove(index);
            System.out.print(users);
        } else {
            System.out.print("not present\n");
            retrait(users);
            boucleretrait = false;
        }
    }
}
```

to this:

```
Scanner element = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("enter name to delete \n");
String elementdelete = element.nextLine();
if (retraitchoix == 1) {
    for (int index = 0; index < users.size(); index++) {
        if (users.get(index).equals(elementdelete)) {
            users.remove(index);
            System.out.print(users);
        }
    }
    System.out.print("not present\n");
    retrait(users);
    boucleretrait = false;
}
```

I've removed the `else`, instead opting to set `boucleretrait` to `false` only after each element in `users` has been checked and the `for` loop has been exited, and also asked the user for a name to search for before the `for` loop so it asks only once before it searches them all.